# Gender language error when pushing source to scratch org

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, scratch-org

After retrieving and unzipping metadata from my sandbox, I ran the command to convert it to the DX model. Using `force:source:push` doesn't work as expected, as I get a looooooooong error log, mainly because objects aren't deployed. I've found that the error is this one:

```
Cannot specify a gender for a gender neutral language
```

I've tried to specify a language attribute to my `.json` configuration file, and then the scratch org is created with the default language of Brazilian Portuguese (which isn't gender neutral). Doing this changes nothing, the problem still happens.

Will I need to manually edit every object file definition to remove the gender, or is there a configuration on the scratch org to allow this deployment?

Comment: Try bringing this to the DX group in the Trailblazer Community. There are still some inconsistent oddities to DX and you might have found one of them.

Comment: @CharlesT do you have a link for this?

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1

Comment: Seems you deleted your post, did you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this issue by specifying the `language` parameter as `pt_BR`. At first, I thought this didn't solve the issue because the error log was huge still. But after trying it again, and inspecting the log for this error, I've seen that it does not occur anymore.